# GridView causes spaces between two table rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html-table

I am not sure if it is the GridView or the ItemTemplate inside the GridView that causes spaces between two table rows:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <asp:RadioButton runat="server" Text="Test" AutoPostBack="true" />
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  <asp:GridView runat="server">
   <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:RadioButton runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Tests").ToString() %>' OnCheckedChanged="GetTestsMethodRequest" AutoPostBack="true" />
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I tried using css for table rows using padding=0 and margin=0 but it didn't work. What is causing the spaces and how can I eliminate them?The output looks:

```
Test


Test1
Test2
Test3
```

**EDIT** If I write the table row with the GridView first and than the second table row I don't get the spaces between the rows. The result is:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test
```

But if I change the position as I did in my first post than i get the spaces between the table rows

Comment: Your grid contains only radio-buttons but your output doesn't show them. So something is wrong, either your output or the grid you've shown.

Comment: Are there 2 line breaks after "Test"?  Code looks fine, but try <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">.  What does the actual html output look like?

Comment: I have tested your grid with a simple DataTable as DataSource and three rows. It looks fine. So the reason for the issue is not the grid, maybe some CSS.

Comment: I edited my question. If I change the position of the table rows it works, but this is not what I want